Optimize multiple react apps loaded around iframe
Context :
I have HTML page, this page load 2 different React apps using iframe =>
<html>
   <iframe src="<served-app-1.html"/>
   <iframe src="<served-app-2.html"/>
   <iframe src="<served-app-3.html"/>
</html>

But I assume that the two applications use some of the same bundle code (as react core) ?
If yes, there is a way to share this part of code one time ?

My solution is to load the lib, I used preact instead of react but it's probably the same solution.
On iframe app, in bundler you used (webpack, vite, ...)
vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import createExternal from "vite-plugin-external";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    createExternal({
      externals: {
        react: "Preact",
      },
    }),
  ],
});

and in the parent html page :
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/preact@10.15.1/dist/preact.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="<served-app-1.html"/>
    <iframe src="<served-app-2.html"/>
    <iframe src="<served-app-3.html"/>
  </body>
</html>

on each served-app index.html, add this tag in head
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    window.preact = window.parent.preact
    console.log("preact loaded from parent window")
  }
</script>

